# Does a long vertical pole fall at a different speed than a short vertical pole?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, acceleration, free-fall

The formula for a falling object has $r^2$ in the denominator.  This would mean that an object that is higher up falls more slowly than the standard $9.807\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$ that we are taught in high school.

What would happen if we took at $1$ metre pole and a $10$ metre pole up to a height of $100$ metres for the bottom of both poles, and then dropped them?   Let's assume they are weighted on the bottom so both remain vertical, and that the $10$ metre pole is hollow so they both weigh the same.  Would they hit the ground simultaneously or otherwise?

Comment: Air resistance neglected or not?

Comment: @fraxinus  No air resistance considered. Purely Newtonian Gravity.  I didn't' need to put in about the weight, but I wanted ONLY the pole length to be considered.

Comment: The effect you are referring to is called "tide."

Comment: One assumes that air resistance is not relevant, as the longer object would have more air resistance over it much greater surface area?  One also assumes that air *buoyancy*  is to be neglected, as otherwise the larger object would *weigh* less even though *massing* the same? Taken to an extreme, the second object might fly like a hydrogen balloon!  And your statement of "Weighted at the bottom" really muddies the situation by **changing the mass distribution** of the longer pole. Is its center of mass higher or lower than for the shorter pole, we don't know!

Comment: Good idea for a question, but stated using very muddy terms. You need to explicitly state the starting environment. You need to not mess with the mass distribution of the poles, or if you do want to do so, then state *exactly* what is being done. "Weighing one end" will do nothing to the orientation of the pole in the absence of air resistance, and is an unnecessary unquantified complication.

Comment: I mean, we can assume a model of the earth that is an infinite plane with uniform gravity above it.  Then the $r^2$ in the denominator goes away.  http://walter.bislins.ch/bloge/index.asp?page=Gravity+on+an+infinite+Flat+Earth+Plane ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Paul T. provides a good answer regarding the case where the height of the bottoms of the poles are the same (which is what was asked for in the question).  The main difference in that case is due to the different heights of the centers of mass of the two rods.

However, you might ask, what if the centers of mass of the two rods were at the same height, would there still be a difference?  It turns out that there will be, although the difference is even smaller.

Let $m$ and $l$ be the mass and length of a vertical rod of uniform density, and $r$ the height of its *center* from the center of the planet.  The planet's mass is $M$.  Consider a tiny piece of the rod, of mass $\delta m$ and distance $x$ from the rod's center (so $x$ is between $-l/2$ and $+l/2$).  The force of gravity on the tiny piece is:

$$\delta F=\frac{GM\delta m}{(r+x)^2}$$

The total force on the rod is the integral of $\delta F$ over the whole mass:

$$F=\int\frac{GM}{(r+x)^2}dm$$

The mass of the small piece is proportional to its length ($m/l=\delta m/\delta x$) so we can substitute $dx$ for $dm$ with the appropriate scaling:

$$F=\int_{-l/2}^{+l/2}\frac{GM}{(r+x)^2}\left(\frac{m}{l}dx\right)$$

Doing the integral yields:

$$\begin{align}
F&=-\frac{GMm}{l}\left.\frac{1}{r+x}\right|_{x=-l/2}^{+l/2} \\
&=-\frac{GMm}{l}\left(\frac{1}{r+l/2}-\frac{1}{r-l/2}\right) \\
&=-\frac{GMm}{l}\left(\frac{(r-l/2)-(r+l/2)}{(r+l/2)(r-l/2)}\right) \\
&=-\frac{GMm}{l}\left(\frac{-l}{r^2-(l/2)^2}\right) \\
&= \frac{GMm}{r^2-(l/2)^2}
\end{align}$$

This is almost the same value as if the mass of the rod was concentrated at its center (in which case it would be just $GMm/r^2$).  Like Paul T., let's look at the relative difference:

$$
\frac{\frac{GMm}{r^2-(l/2)^2}-\frac{GMm}{r^2}}{\frac{GMm}{r^2}} 
= \frac{(r^2)-(r^2-(l/2)^2)}{r^2-(l/2)^2} 
= \frac{(l/2)^2}{r^2-(l/2)^2} 
\approx \left(\frac{l}{2r}\right)^2
$$

Compare this to the case where we measure $r$ from the end of the pole, where the relative difference (between a rod and a point) was just $l/r$.  If the end case had a difference of on part per million, the center case will have a difference of less than one part per trillion!

Comment: I was wondering when somebody was going to answer this with calculus because indeed, this is a calculus question.     Well done   ;)

Answer (score 26):

Yes.  As described in the questions, there is very small difference between the acceleration of the two poles with the shorter one accelerating faster.

## The difference

The gravitational force acting on a pole is
$$F = \frac{GMm}{r^2},$$
where $M$ is the mass of the Earth, $m$ is the mass of the pole, and $r$ is the separation between the center of mass (CoM) of the Earth and the CoM of the pole.  Neglecting air resistance and the gravitational effect of one pole on the other, the acceleration of a pole is
$$a = F/m = \frac{GM}{r^2}.$$
The masses of the poles don't matter.  They could be different or the same.

If the two poles are different lengths, $L > \ell$, then their CoMs will be at different distances from the CoM of the earth.
Let's define $R$ as the distance from the CoM of the Earth to the bottom of the polls, which are at the same height.
Assuming the poles are uniform
$$r_\ell = R + \ell/2 \quad\text{and}\quad r_L= R + L/2.$$

The shorter pole will will experience a larger acceleration.

$$ a_\ell = \frac{GM}{(R + \ell/2)^2} \quad > \quad a_L = \frac{GM}{(R + L/2)^2}$$

## How big is the difference?

To get a handle on how much larger, we can do a first order expansion of the two accelerations and look at the difference.
$$a_L = \frac{GM}{r^2} = \frac{GM}{(R + L/2)^2} = \frac{GM}{R^2(1+\frac{L}{2R})^2} = \frac{GM}{R^2}\left(1 + \frac{L}{2R}\right)^{-2}\approx \frac{GM}{R^2}\left(1 - 2 \frac{L}{2R}\right)$$

I personally find the fractional difference $\frac{\Delta a}{a}$ to be more illuminating than the absolute. So lets look at that by dividing out the common $GM/R^2$ bit.
$$\frac{\Delta a}{a} \approx \frac{a_\ell - a_L}{GM/R^2} \approx (1- \ell/R) - (1-L/R) = \frac{L-\ell}{R}$$

The radius of the Earth is about $6\times 10^6$ m, so we're looking at parts-per-million differences in the accelerations of the two poles.

Comment: I'll ask you a question I asked above.  Do we use the centre of gravity of the earth and of the pole just for mathematical convenience, or is there a more precise way if we did a derivative calculation on the entire length of both?  I know it's a strange question, but I'm trying to get a handle on exactly how things fall in relation to spacetime.

Comment: In general you must integrate over the two mass distributions to figure out the force of every part of one body on every part of the other.  Spherically symmetric things act like perfect point masses at their CoMs.  The Earth isn't quite a sphere, so there are small $\sim\frac{1}{R^4}$ quadrupole corrections to the force due to its shape.  You might want to look up [mass quadrupole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole#Gravitational_quadrupole) or [multipole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion)

Comment: If you are thinking about falling and spacetime, you might want look into general relativity instead of Newtonian gravity.

Comment: Would the answer to the OP under GR be any different?

Comment: "Assuming the poles are uniform " is contradictory to the OP's statement that " Let's assume they are weighted on the bottom so both remain vertical" (which, BTW, would not work if air resistance is not considered)

Comment: If the poles are long enough (as in realllllly long), they could even float above earth, right? Similar to the concepts for space elevators.

Comment: @EricDuminil No - gravity extends infinitely far, and always points down. No matter how far you are from earth, you can fall straight down to it by gravity alone. You're talking about putting things into orbit, which has nothing to do with a reduction in gravity but instead just moving sideways really fast. A space elevator is held up by a centrifugal force from the speed of its orbit, but it's still being pulled down by gravity at all times - it's just orbiting fast enough so that it never falls to the ground. No matter how high you put the COM, gravity pulls it *down*.

Comment: @foolishmuse:  It wouldn't be significantly different under GR.  I haven't done the calculations, but I would expect there would be even smaller corrections on the order of $(L-\ell)^2/R^2$;  but that would introduce a parts-per-million difference *in the difference*, and would be correspondingly harder to detect.

Comment: This neglects terminal velocity and other aerodynamics though. And given the mass is equal this has a major influence since skin drag is much higher for a larger object. (Even though pressure drag would be less). Given that the OP indicates the pole is weighted at the bottom to keep it straight, this indicates he considers aerodynamic forces. (Otherwise the weighting isn't needed).

Comment: @paul23:  The OP specified in a comment on the original question that air resistance should be neglected.  There may be something of a contradiction there, though.

Comment: @paul23 To all regarding the OP, yes I am assuming no air resistance. I added the note about a weight at the bottom just so that any reader understood that the poles remain vertical because this is the key part of the question.   And I added the hollow long pole just so that mass would not be a consideration.

Comment: If you are neglecting interactions with the atmosphere then you don't need non-uniform mass distribution to get a straight fall.  It should be sufficient to start with uniform-density cylindrical poles aligned parallel to the gravity vector.  With no other forces acting on the poles, there is then nothing that would introduce any net tangential force.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  Yes, absolutely.  In fact with the spagettification mentioned elsewhere, the tendency to remain vertical would be very strong.  Unfortunately, this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcvq1DAM-DE strongly implies that a falling object wants to turn in space.  But in all of this we come to understand that if the poles were horizontal, they would  land at the same time, but being vertical, they land at different time - all due to the gradient of time dilation.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I wasn't talking about a reduction in gravity. If the pole is so long that the center of mass is at a geostationary orbit : the far side of the pole would need to rotate really fast in order for the pole to stay vertical. The whole pole would be in orbit (ignoring air drag on the nearest side, or putting it above the atmosphere). It would fall, but it would always miss the earth. Could that work?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming (reasonably) that both objects are rigid (undergo no deformation under the influence of gravity) then in the Law:

$$F=G\frac{mM}{r^2}$$

$r$ refers to the distance between the centre of gravity (CoG) of the object and the CoG of the Earth.

Then assuming the CoGs of both objects have the same mass and are at the same height above the Earth (at the start of their free fall), the resulting $F$ are equal.

> Would they hit the ground simultaneously or otherwise?

In those circumstances the former would be true.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that it won't be exactly true if their individual masses were different ( and the rods were far apart from each other ).

Comment: @NakshatraGangopadhay Made an edit. Your second conditions seems very implicit to me though.

Comment: Most books teach wrongly that different masses experiencing the same acceleration automatically imply that they reach the surface of the earth at the same time. The problem with this is that, even though they have the same acceleration, one of them has to cover a shorter distance. The heavier object will have a common center of mass with the Earth, closer to itself than the lighter object, and will thus travel a shorter distance compared to the lighter object. A very subtle point, that many seem to miss.

Comment: @NakshatraGangopadhay Seems to me the question has been asked at the level of middle school, where that sort of subtelty isn't yet taught, understandably.

Comment: @Gert If I am not wrong, the CoGs for two poles will fall together simultaneously (if they are at same height) till the bottom of the longer pole touches the ground (since bottom of the longer pole is more closer to the ground)

Comment: The question says "height of 100 m for the bottom of both poles" but your answer says "assuming CoGs of  both objects are at the same height". You have answered a question different from the one asked.

Comment: @Nakshatra There's a good question on that topic, linked below, in the Related section: *Don't heavier objects actually fall faster because they exert their own gravity?* The effect for small bodies on Earth is on the order of 1 part in 10²⁴.

Comment: @NakshatraGangopadhay it's really a bit pedantic to call that _wrong_. Not only because in practice the effect is utterly negligible for any object you could actually lift, but also in theory because it's the _Earth's_ movement that makes the tiny difference. The objects would still reach the surface at the same time if the Earth hadn't moved closer by that time in the heavier case.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, slightly different acceleration as others have said, leading to slightly later arrival of the longer pole. (It is the location of the centre of mass which determines the acceleration).

An interesting related effect: the poles are both drawn into tension owing to the different gravitational pull on their two ends. The extreme example of this is the 'spaghettification' predicted to happen as things fall towards the centre of a black hole.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, no air. Also I simplify out the tidal effects (poles are in no sense spherical). Mutual attraction between poles, as well as the Earth moving towards them assumed negligible (not that it will change the answer).

Other than that, 10m pole has its centre of mass 4.5m higher so it gets somewhat less gravity and less acceleration.

Since both poles have to travel 100m (equal distance), the 10m pole will arrive later.

Answer (score 2):

In non uniform gravity, discounting air resistance,  any two objects having different heights for their centers of gravity will be accelerated by gravity at different rates. As you seem to understand, the increased radius to the center of gravity would give a lower rate of initial acceleration to the higher object..

Comment: The centre of gravity.  That makes perfect sense.  Are you certain of this versus the height of the top of the pole?  Or is centre of gravity just used for mathematical simplicity?

Comment: I guess that would also pose the question is the centre of the earth just used for mathematical simplicity?

Comment: The COG is the point of the objects gravitational equilibrium. In non uniform gravity the COG will be slightly different than its COM.. When considering gravitational attraction between Earth and much much smaller objects the difference in Earth's COM and its COG relative to the smaller object is normally inconsequential

Answer (score -1):

Actually the question is a little vague. When I read it, I thought it meant like a tree, or a telegraph pole, or one of those very tall old chimneys falling over. In which case we are calculating the time for a tall thin cylinder to fall over. The taller it is, the longer it will take to fall although in real life we would have to contend with the cylinder breaking or deforming.
Most of the answers here focus on dropping a vertical cylinder and have answered that thoroughly. There is also the possibility of the cylinder (pole) being held horizontally before being dropped in which case the length would not be relevant.
I hope that has muddied the waters a little...

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.