# Why isnt a taller object more buoyant?

Tags: water, fluid-statics, density, buoyancy

If an objects buoyancy is dependant on the difference in pressure between its two faces, why arent taller objects more buoyant since the pressure difference is larger?

Comment: This post needs some details about what is assumed to be different and what is assumed to be the same in the comparison. @BioPhysicist assumed that the cross-section was the same and the volume changed. I would have assumed that the volume was the same and the shape changed. Please clarify, as both interpretations are valid based on the current wording. Density, mass, volume, shape, area, etc.

Comment: @Dale True, it does impact the first part of my answer, but not the second part. More clarity would be nice though

Comment: Actually, do be aware that now that you have received an answer, you cannot modify the question in a way that invalidates the answer by @BioPhysicist

Comment: @Dale I am following the question, so I can edit if needed. That is the best general principle to follow though

Answer (score 2):

The taller object (assuming the same cross-sectional area) actually does have a larger buoyant force acting on it since it displaces more fluid (or equivalently, it has a larger pressure difference between its ends, as you stated).

However, the taller object will also have more mass (assuming the same material for both objects and a constant cross-sectional area). If we compare the buoyant force $\frac{\rho_\text{water}}{\rho_\text{object}}m_\text{object}g$ and the weight $m_\text{object}g$ we see that the acceleration of each object will be the same regardless of volume:

$$a=\left(\frac{\rho_\text{water}}{\rho_\text{object}}-1\right)g$$

So the "buoyancy" (at least what I think you mean by this) is unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about the upward buoyant forces on objects having the same volume and density, but different shapes (in this case, one "taller" than the other). If that's the case, two objects having the same volume and density will have the same buoyant force regardless of their shapes or orientation.

For example, let one object be a rectangular solid and the other a cubic solid of the same density and volume. See the Fig below where both objects are completely submerged.

The pressure difference between the upper and lower faces of the vertically oriented rectangular solid will be greater than the difference for the cubic solid shown below. But the cross sectional areas of the top and bottom faces of the rectangular solid will be less than the cubic solid, such that the product of the cross sectional area and pressure difference, which equals the buoyant force, is the same.

Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: Bob D, please allow me to question this.   I'm reading that "The center of buoyancy  is the center of mass (or center of gravity) of the displaced water.  The buoyancy force acts through this point."    To me, it seems that this means that since the the centre of mass of the water displaced by the two objects would be at different depths, then they would not rise at the same rate since the buoyant force acts differently at different depths.  I'm comparing to this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/662423/does-a-long-vertical-pole-fall-at-a-different-speed-than-a-short-vertical-pole

Comment: I have answered my own question just above.  The buoyant force remains the same.  However, because acceleration due to this buoyancy is time dependent, the two blocks will not hit the surface at the same time (assuming they start with their top at the same level.)  The taller block has it's center of buoyancy at a lower level, so it will have longer to accelerate in terms of distance and time.

Comment: @foolishmuse You are referring to an "acceleration", but my analysis is based on the assumption of equilibrium which is the case as long as the density of the object is equal to or less than the density of the liquid so that the object floats either totally or partially submerged. My diagram assumed the object floats totally submerged. But if you've answered your own question, that's fine.